# alignment issue in Div : html

Tags: html

I'm trying to middle vertically align for text in Div but it is not working . Can someone please suggest alternative option. I'm using Mozila browser .

```
<td width="47.32%" style="vertical-align: middle; margin: 0px;">
    <div id="dateRangeLbl" style="vertical-align: middle;">
      Aug 21,2013
    </div>
</td>
```

Seems issue is coming due to below CSS . but my requirment is to dispay image on tob of Image .

```
   #dateRangeLbl:hover {
    background-image: url(<%=contextPath%>/images/dateRangeHover_bg.png);
    cursor:hand;
    color: #0066cc;
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/grBK7/ -- seems to work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a table with a single row and a single column. The element `td` supports vertical and horizontal text align without having to make any CSS tricks and it works the same in all browsers. Using CSS, you would apply these to the `td`:

```
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

To vertically align something, set the `display` for the element to `inline-block`, then `vertical-align: middle` for the content: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/

Answer (score 0):

This CSS rule solved my problem:

```
#dateRangeLbl{
     padding : 5px 0px 0px 0px ;
}
```